# Baysick InternalDSL

Tags: scala, functional-programming, compiler-construction, dsl

I am working on an InternalDSL project similar to the [Baysick](https://github.com/fogus/baysick/blob/master/src/main/scala/fogus/baysick/samples/Lunar.scala) for building a compiler.I understand some part of the code [here](https://github.com/fogus/baysick/blob/master/src/main/scala/fogus/baysick/Baysick.scala). In the file `Baysick.scala`, there are implicit functions, they are fetching line numbers, assignments, symbols etc and they are fed into corresponding case classes.

Can someone here please explain me how this `('dist := 100)` expression is being parsed? what implicit functions are used here and what are it's corresponding case classes. What's happening actually inside?

And also, what is `appendr()` doing here?

Answer (score 1):

First, `'dist` is a Symbol literal, so it will be converted to something like `Symbol("dist")`.

Then, `:=` is parsed as an infix operator and called as a method. If it were a method of `Symbol`, then the result would be `Symbol("dist").:=(100)`. However, there is no such method.

Now, implicit method resolution comes into play. It will find out that there is a unique implicit function in scope, say `symbol2Assignment`, which will "fit the type slot"; that is, it has to have a type like

```
Symbol => { def :=(i: Int): Unit }
```

(modulo subtyping), which stands for "convert the `Symbol` to something that has a suitable `:=` method". This function is then applied, and we get

```
symbol2Assignment(Symbol("dist")).:=(100)
```

which is valid, since `Assignment <: { def :=(i: Int): Unit }`. This method then closes over some dictionary which it modifies.

Answer (score 0):

The literal with the single initial tick is called a `Symbol`.

Searching the code, I found

```
 case class Assignment(sym:Symbol)
```

which also has `:=` methods.

According to its scaladoc text, it is created by the implicit method `symbol2Assignment`.

Note, that you can use `implicit class` nowadays, does both, the class and the implicit conversion in one step. It is also recommended.

Comment: As I said above, I am clear that implicit functions and the corresponding case classes to each of them. But how this ('dist := 100) is converted to scala or maybe parsed into scala.

Comment: I may be understanding wrong, but there is no real parsing and and all the values are already Scala values. That is the point about internal DSLs. They are not separate languages, just quirky ways of talking.

In case of `('dist := 100)`, this will add a key value pair `('dist,100)` to `binds`, which is of type `Binding[String,Int]`.  An object of type Binding, is there defined basically as a map, that can take two different kinds of values, in this case strings and integers.